# PHP code not linking properly missing code

Tags: php

Here is what I have. I have an index php page sitting on my /root/ folder with the following code:

```
index.php

require_once("access/$template/head.php");
```

My functions page has the following configuration for the $template code:

`funcs.php`

```
function getTemplateFiles() { 
    $directory = "models/site-templates/"; 
    $languages = glob($directory . "*");  
    return $languages; 
}
```

My head php page has the following code:

head.php

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='$template/css/style.css'>
```

My question is what code can I add to my index page that will communicate with my head page, a code before my $template that will include the file location of my php page.

Example 1

```
$include_dir/$template/css/style.css'>
```

My question being is how can I include the path of my index page so that my head page will read as html like so?

default, does not work `$template/css/style.css`

need it like this only for the index page `access/$template/css/style.css`

Comment: Am not reading anything but this `$template/css/style.css` should be `<?php echo $template.'/css/style.css'; ?>`

Comment: The whole argument reads like so...<?php
echo "  <link rel='stylesheet' href='$template/css/style.css'> ";

?>

Comment: The code works fine for pages inside the main directory where the $template php code is located

Comment: do you know that `getTemplateFiles()` returns array?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='$template/css/style.css'>
```

Use this

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='<?php echo $template; ?>/css/style.css'>
```

Comment: That is not the whole code it echo's this code on my index php page:    <?php echo models/site-templates/rd-web_design-black_colours; ?>/css/style.css'>

Comment: use single or double quota like this : <?php echo "models/site-templates/rd-web_design-black_colours"; ?>

Comment: The code works fine for pages inside the main directory where the $template php code is located

Comment: I would rather move my site-template folder and rename my funcs.php code to $directory = "/access/models/site-templates/";

Comment: where are $template define ?

Comment: hey sonusindhu how did you know the directory path?

Comment: @user2555525 you used $template variable so we want to know where it is defined or declare in your page.

Comment: function getTemplateFiles() { 
    $directory = "models/site-templates/"; 
    $languages = glob($directory . "*");  
    return $languages; 
}

Comment: Doesn't that code define the location of the variable which then defines models/site-templates/rd-web_design-black_colours

Comment: used like this : $template = getTemplateFiles(); before include head.php ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure whether I understand your problem correctly, but these two methods might help:

```
$currentDir = dirname(__FILE__);
```

`$currentDir` will be the path on your server to the file you're currently in. So if you have a structure like this:

/access/functions/myFunction.php

and you're calling this method from myFunction.php, `$currentDir` will return '/access/functions'. If the file to be included is in the same directory-path, you can include it like this:

```
$includePath = $currentDir."/myFile.php";
```

Another way of determining a target directory is using:

```
$docRoot = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
```

`$docRoot` will be the top-directory of your website (usually something like /usr/www/username/public_html/)

Using this, you always know what your top-directory is and then you can include files like this:

```
$includePath = $docRoot."/models/site-templates/myTemplate.css";
```